# Replace text file line by line number

Tags: php

How to delete a line from a text file based on the line number and replace it with new line?
for example edit file.txt with php:
Before run script:

```
Line 1: replace
Line 2: line
Line 3: with
Line 4: script
```

After run script:

```
Line 1: replace
Line 2: line
Line 3: with
Line 4: PHP script
```

I tested with the following code. But it doesn't run on the host. Do you have a better solution?

```
$arr = file('file.txt'); // text to array

$content = "";
$needle = 3; // the line number you want to edit
$replace = 'PHP script'; // the replacement text

foreach($arr as $key => $line) {
    if($line[0] == $needle) {
        $arr[$key] = $needle . " $replace" . PHP_EOL;
    }
    $content .= $arr[$key]; // rebuild your text file
}

echo 'The new text file contents:' . PHP_EOL;
echo $content;
// overwrite text file with edited content
file_put_contents('file.txt', $content);
```

Comment: _"But it doesn't run on the host"_ - So what happens? Does it work locally? Done any debugging? Do you have write permission on that file?

Comment: Because `$line[0]` will never `== $needle` What do you think `$line[0]` will be anyway. It will be the First Character of the string of each line i.e. it will be `L` as strings can be treated as arrays

Comment: Permission 777. Runs online but not on hosts. https://3v4l.org/2Tae2

Comment: What was that comment suppose to answer?

Comment: **So your example INPUT file is in fact NOTHING LIKE THE REAL FILE** Now thats helpful

Comment: isnt `$line[0]` start of the lines in text file? and example is working fine probably not finding text file location @RiggsFolly

Comment: @dilekkoç No, its the first character of `$line` and `$line` will be each Line in turn as you loop through the `$arr` array in the foreach loop

Comment: @baharan Line 1 is actual Line 0. Arrays start from INDEX 0, not INDEX 1.

Comment: @RiggsFolly got it thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you use the fact that `file_put_contents()` can take an array and just write it out, there is a simpler version which just takes the original contents of `file()` (including the new lines it will load automatically) and then replace the corresponding line (using array notation `[$needle]`) but add a new line onto the data (`PHP_EOL` to be generic).  Then just write this array out.

```
$arr = file('file.txt'); // text to array

$content = "";
$needle = 3; // the line number you want to edit
$replace = 'PHP script'; // the replacement text

$arr[$needle] = $replace . PHP_EOL;
file_put_contents('file.txt', $arr);
```

Answer (score 2):

You could use the `array_splice` method to modify the array that is created when a file is read using `file` - this could be modified to also search for the content that is to be replaced quite easily.

```
<?php

    $file=__DIR__ . '/srctext.txt';

    $line=4;
    $replace = 'Banana';


    $lines=file( $file, FILE_IGNORE_NEW_LINES );
    array_splice( $lines, $line, 1, $replace );
    file_put_contents($file,implode("\n",$lines));

?>
```

Answer (score -1):

Here is the code that fixes your problem. Feel free to ask in comment if anything is unclear.

```
<?php
// Please note that starting index in a file, array is ZERO not ONE as in your example

$edited_file_data = file('file.txt', FILE_IGNORE_NEW_LINES ); // text to array which ommits new lines (thanks Nigel)

$line_to_replace     = 3;            // the line number you want to edit
$replacement_content = 'PHP script'; // the replacement text


$edited_file_data[$line_to_replace] = $replacement_content;

echo 'The new text file contents:' . PHP_EOL;

$new_file_data_as_string = implode("\r\n", $edited_file_data);
echo $new_file_data_as_string;

// overwrite text file with edited content
file_put_contents('file.txt', $new_file_data_as_string);
?>
```

Working example on the page you tested:
https://3v4l.org/IcWGE

Comment: There are a few syntax errors and other problems in your code - worth testing it.

Comment: I wrote the answer in notepad and haven't noticed them first time. I updated the code.

Comment: @besciualex thanks for answer. but after run your script Blank lines are created.

Comment: This depends on the OS where this script is run. Use \n instead of \r\n. Or '' (simple empty quotes) if you don't want no lines at all.

Comment: Although it isn't my downvote - using `file()` without `FILE_IGNORE_NEW_LINES` will mean that the array values will have the new lines left in, when you then `implode()` with new lines added, you will add an extra line each time.

Comment: Thank you for pointing that out. I updated my answer and credited you there. :)